# why my object detection training loss is very low (<1),but the precision is still 0?

Tags: object-detection, object-detection-api, mobilenet

I am using colab to train an object detection model, please check the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Xe_t8FNVMyaQ7DRnziSmM_N156ikoowC#scrollTo=RPN8liiQc7Ue). But i found the loss is very low, the presion is still zero, what is the wrong ?
[image: U58QAA.png]

Answer (score 0):

Fine, i should be patient, after trainiing 10000 steps, the prediction box comes out. In my case, the precision is low maybe is because i implement many tricks to simplify the model complexity and squeeze the model file size.